# `NotRegistered` Exception when using multiple inheritance

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

This is really frustrating.

Below are my document definitions, in order to have sub-class documents inherit from a base class, I followed the suggestion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoengine-users/T8lCtGv_IYQ

models/thread.py

```
class Thread(object):
    meta = {
        'allow_inheritance': True
    }
```

models/forum.py

```
from models.thread import Thread
from mongoengine import Document

class ForumThread(Document, Thread):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'forum_threads'
    }
```

models/group.py

```
from models.thread import Thread
from mongoengine import Document

class GroupThread(Document, Thread):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'group_threads'
    }
```

I am getting the `NotRegistered` when attempting something of this sort;

```
>>> from models.forum import ForumThread
>>> print ForumThread.objects().first()
>>> NotRegistered: `Thread` has not been registered in the document registry.
            Importing the document class automatically registers it, has it
            been imported?
```

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Has `Thread` been imported?

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure Thread needs a `meta`, alternatively try with an abstract base class[1]

```
class Thread(Document):
    meta = {
        'abstract': True
    }

class ForumThread(Thread):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'forum_threads'
    }

class GroupThread(Thread):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'group_threads'
    }
```

[1] http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#abstract-classes

Comment: This gives me an KeyError: 'id_field' when attempting to query. All I want is a single place to define the thread fields, and a way to represent threads in multiple collections.

Comment: does the `id_field` meta attribute need to be set on all abstract classes? When adding that to the Thread.__meta__ dict, I no longer am able to access mongoengine documents `_id` field as `id` in code.

Comment: I've also tried setting Thread._meta['id_field'] to `id` and `_id` to no avail. All our documents have an `_id` field. Thanks for the help Ross.

Comment: the `_cls` field on the existing docs was the issue. http://docs.mongoengine.org/upgrade.html#document-definition